# PHP AJAX request stops working suddenly on localhost

Tags: php, ajax, localhost

this is my ajax script

```
$('#login-form').submit(function(event) {
/* Act on the event */
event.preventDefault();
var form_data = $(this).serialize();
var url = $(this).attr('action');
$.post(url, form_data, function(message){
    if(message == 1){
        window.location.href    =   'home.php';
    }else{
        $('#login-form span.error').html(message).show(100);
        $('#login-form')[0].reset();
    }

    }); //end of post function

});// end of submit function
```

and this is my php script (part of script) to handle above pasted ajax request

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
$login_result   =   runQuery($login_query);
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($login_result);
if($row_count>0){
    echo $row_count;
}else{
    echo "Email/Password is incorrect";
}
```

this was working fine till yesterday but today im getting just "1" (in case email and password is correct) or "Email/Password is incorrect" otherwise.

[image]

i am unable to figure it out.

Comment: Looks like it works..  It's returns `1` which I guess is the number of rows

Comment: yes it is working , but not in the way it is supposed to be. in case of success it should redirect me as per the code below (and that was happening till yesterday) $.post(url, form_data, function(message){
    if(message == 1){
        window.location.href    =   'home.php';

Comment: So then, what does `message` contain on the client side? Only you can tell us...

Comment: its a page                                                                                                              $.post(url, form_data, function(message){
    if(message == 1){
        window.location.href    =   'home.php';                                               
   and it is not blank and it was working fine till yesterday

Comment: That certainly is _not_ the content of the variable `message`. So what is it?

Comment: it is what is returned by    if($row_count>0){
    echo $row_count;
}else{
    echo "Email/Password is incorrect";
}

Comment: Can you just do a `console.log` of `message` inside the `$.post` function before anything else happens? It looks like it isn't even possible, your code shows it should redirect the user to `home.php` which it isn't doing at all. 

If it was working yesterday and not today then maybe check if you made changes in the code that you didn't save before testing it out and now that you have it causes this issue.

Comment: message is just a name of parameter used to recv what is sent by the php script, in my case its "1" or "Email/Password is incorrect". i have not changed the code